# How do I load a PHP Class?

Tags: php, postgresql, pomm

I use [Pomm 1.1.4](http://pomm.coolkeums.org/) and I cannot load the class. [Here](http://api.odtu.lu/v1/) `it says Fatal error: Class 'Pomm\Connection\Database' not found in /users/ilhanna/public_html/api/v1/Pomm-1.1.4/Pomm/Service.php on line 38` There is nothing on line 38, just a comment. My code to load the class is

```
require_once 'Pomm-1.1.4/Pomm/Service.php';
# Using the constructor
$service = new Pomm\Service(array(
  'db_one' => array(
    'dsn' => 'pgsql://username:password@localhost:5432/databasename'
  )
  ));
```

I am missing something I think.

Comment: is that class defined as being inside a `Pomm` namespace?

Comment: @MarcB, I think so https://gist.github.com/ilhanyumer/7881805

Comment: If you intend to use only one database, unless you are using an injection container, I would advise you to directly instanciate a Database instance.

Comment: @greg, by using the setDatabase method?

Comment: @ilhan just do $db = new \Pomm\Connection\Database(array(...)); Once you have a database instance, you can issue as many connection as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use composer to install Pomm and get an autoloader. Download `composer.phar` from [packagist](https://packagist.org/)

create a composer.json file like this:

```
{
"require": {
    "pomm/pomm": "~1.1"
  }
}
```

and execute the phar to install Pomm. Just add the following code in your index.php

```
$loader = require __DIR__."/vendors/autoload.php";
```

If you cannot use composer, create your own autoload mechanism:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    if (0 === strpos($class, 'Pomm\\')) {
        $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
        require sprintf("%s/%s.php", __DIR__, $class);
}
```

at the very begining of your index.php file and it should run fine.

Comment: I have decided to use the autoloader that you have created manually. It works. ( https://gist.github.com/ilhanyumer/7882935 )

Answer (score 1):

Your `Service.php` file includes the class `Service` which has two other class dependencies. The error is for the missing `Database` class.

```
  namespace Pomm;

  use Pomm\Connection\Database; // Error line (class missing) 
  use Pomm\Exception\Exception;
```

You will need to have these classes also loaded prior to you creating a service instance. If the files are located within the same directory as the service class; you could just include them before.

```
require_once 'Pomm-1.1.4/Pomm/Datebase.php';
require_once 'Pomm-1.1.4/Pomm/Exception.php';
require_once 'Pomm-1.1.4/Pomm/Service.php';

$service = new Pomm\Service(array(
  'db_one' => array(
    'dsn' => 'pgsql://username:password@localhost:5432/databasename'
  )
));
```

A better solution would be to look into [PHP auto-loading](http://php.net/autoload); perhaps a [package manager such as Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) if you project is a bit larger.